# InMemory HTML and Images for .NET MAUI WebView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, webview, maui

```
WebView webView = new WebView
{
    Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
        Html = @"<!DOCTYPE html><HTML>
<BODY>
<H1>.NET MAUI</H1>
<P>Welcome to WebView.</P>
<img src=""myimg.jpg"" alt=""My Image"" width=""500"" height=""600"">
</BODY>
</HTML>",
    },
};
```

I wanted to write something like this. Having `HTML`-string in memory to be displayed.
Images, Audios and potentially Vidoes should also be loaded from memory.

What must I do to add an `Handler` to `webView` or `webView.Source` that is called, when the image should be loaded so that I can return an `byte[]` with the data should be interpreted as image, sound or video?

I have search in the web and found some ideas

`webView.Source.Load(new MauiWKWebView());`

But I have no ASP.NET project ...

It works in this [example][1] if images are added as static resource.
But my media data is stored in a database.

Comment: [Image / Load an image from a stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image?view=net-maui-7.0#load-an-image-from-a-stream) shows C# `... Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream)`. Load the image from DB into a memory stream just before the code you show. (I don't know whether that Load can be deferred; first get it working this way.)

Comment: You can develop a web app and add your media data to it, then you can display the media data to webview.

Comment: Hi Jessie, thanks, but can you explain it please more detailed? I don't know how a webapp can be usefull on an Smartphone device. I want to avoid the call to an external web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `WebView`, the only way to render image I'm avare of is to set it's content as `base64` string.
Doing so, your example would look something like this:

```
var htmlString = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<BODY>
<H1>.NET MAUI</H1>
<P>Welcome to WebView.</P>
<img src=""data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="" alt=""Red dot"">
</BODY>
</HTML>";

var webView = new WebView
{
    Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
      Html = htmlString
    }
};
```

Assuming you have image data in `byte[]` form, you can use this to convert it to `base64 string` :

```
var imageBytes = ...;
var base64ImageString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```